Ubuntu 22 Docker container can't set promiscuous mode in a Dockerfile, but can on command line
Hope this is the right place to ask vs SO, ServerFault, etc. I've searched a lot and can't find anything remotely like this question, ready to be proven a bad searcher.
When I build a Ubuntu 22-based Docker container and run bash on it, I can run the command in the container:
ip link set dev eth0 promisc on
But when I put that into a Dockerfile, I get an error when the command runs during build.
Question is, why is there a difference? And how can I make it work in a Dockerfile?
Build command is: docker build -t firewall .
I've tried it with --allow=network.host just for fun, no difference.
When I run the built container, I do use --privileged, if that matters.
Here's what the error looks like: (image too https://imgur.com/a/SrWcoFZ)
=> ERROR [23/23] RUN ip link set dev eth0 promisc on                                                                
------                                                                                                             
> [23/23] RUN ip link set dev eth0 promisc on:
0.200 RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
------
<snip a warning about running in a Git dir>
Dockerfile:35
--------------------
33 |     RUN cd snort3-3.1.43.0/build && make install
34 |     RUN ldconfig
35 | >>> RUN ip link set dev eth0 promisc on 
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c ip link set dev eth0 promisc on" did not complete successfully: exit code: 2

Background: I'm trying to run Snort in a Docker container, it's part of building a project for a MS-level security course. One step of installing Snort is setting the network interface to promiscuous, if I understand correctly this lets Snort see all network traffic, regardless of destination. I see this in standard Snort installs, I don't really understand why I care about more than the traffic directly addressed to the container. Maybe this isn't even needed?
And in case it matters this is all happening inside a VM based on Ubuntu 24.04, long story short. And I'm building the project in a git repo, at the top level dir, I snipped out the warning about that.
So the bottom line thing I'm not understanding, why is this behaving differently when running it as part of a Docker build vs running it manually in the container once the container is up?
Thanks
UPDATE: Based on comments I setup an ENTRYPOINT script, but I still have the same problem:
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted occurs when I run this container, here's the Dockerfile and startup script:
https://github.com/jimlohse/firewallProjectPublic
UPDATE 2 I was being dumb and forgetting to use --privileged when I added the ENTRYPOINT script. Once I started using that flag, it works. Thanks!
Accepted the answer, thanks for addressing my conceptual understanding.

Fwiw this is the warning I snipped out "WARNING: current commit information was not captured by the build: failed to read current commit information with git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree" I'm assuming this is completely irrelevant

I did find this https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/902, am I just thinking about this wrong? Is it possible to set the network interface to promiscuous when I run Docker, instead of during the build? Sorry Docker newb here.

What would even be the point of running this during build? When you actually run the container, you'd need to do it again for whichever interface is available in the container

I don't understand how I'd run it as a command when I actually run the container, you're saying I should use something like docker run --privileged -it firewall ip set link...? Actually trying to start multiple containers with docker compose, I'll look into that thanks.

Your image's ENTRYPOINT can be a script which runs this ip command and then executes the actual command specified for the container

sorry was commenting and your most recent comment had not popped up yet. I'll look into this thanks.

OK I made a startup script and put an ENTRYPOINT in calling the script. I get the same error RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
LOL how frustrating. Thus the original question remains, why will this run manually in the container and not through automated means. I'm updating the question with a repo link soon.
Please don't rip my Dockerfile I know I need to clean it up, any pointers welcome thanks


So the bottom line thing I'm not understanding, why is this behaving differently when running it as part of a Docker build vs running it manually in the container once the container is up?

A Docker container runs with a default set of restrictions that prevent you from performing potentially sensitive tasks, such as changing the network configuration, mounting filesystems, etc. The ephemeral containers used during the docker build process include these same restrictions.
When you start a container with --privileged, you are removing all of the default restrictions, so that a container has full access to system devices, the network stack, mount operations, etc.
Generally it doesn't make any sense to grant these privileges during the build process, because the build process is ephemeral -- if you need a specific network configuration, that's something you would need to up at runtime, not at build time.
In your example, you're attempting to run:
RUN ip link set dev eth0 promisc on 

But that doesn't do anything. It doesn't make a persistent change that gets stored in the container image and it won't have any impact on the running container.
If you need to enable promiscuous mode on an interface, then:

You will need to do it at runtime, via your CMD or ENTRYPOINT script, and
You will need to grant the container additional privileges, either by removing all restrictions with --privileged or by granting a smaller subset of privileges with something like --cap-add net_admin.

